# How to distinguish between right (as in right and wrong) and right (as in left-right)?

Tags: meaning

If you tell me to take the right car shall I take the not left car or the not wrong car?

Comment: Toss a coin.  Or use "port" and "starboard".  (This is a common source of confusion, though only rarely does it result in serious problems.)

Comment: There isn't an easy way, so confusion of the two in conversation is a staple for lazy writers. *It's absolutely vital we make the next turn. Left? Right. Wait, where are we going‽ Well, you said 'right'!*

Comment: I'd say, we'll take the Porsche not the Volkswagen. Plus if you don't have the keys, you won't be 'taking' either car.

Comment: My favorite is when someone is giving me directions and I ask them something along the lines, "take the next left right?"

Comment: There's no wright way to do it I'm afraid.

Comment: You can tell someone has flight experience talking to aircraft control because they are trained to never use the word 'right' to mean 'correct' or 'yes'. They use the word 'affirmative' for 'yes' as a matter of policy.

Answer (score 10):

A native speaker wouldn't tell you to take the "right car", when he means "the car on the right".
When in doubt, context is everything.

Comment: I think I (BrEng speaker) possibly use "the right-hand one" more often than "the one on the right" when distinguishing two things. Never "the right one" unless I was referring to a part of the body or an article of clothing (e.g. the right foot, the left glove).

Comment: @mikeagg: As a BrE speaker tbh I would definitely say "the one on the right".

Answer (score 5):

It pretty much depends on context. If someone talks about "making a right turn," you can pretty safely assume they mean right-left right, and if someone talks about "making the right decision," they clearly mean right-wrong right. If the context doesn't help, as in your example, you could rephrase it slightly, such as saying "the car on the right" to mean the right-left right car or "the correct car" to mean the right-wrong right car.

Comment: Apparently Dennis Williamson and I were typing at the same time.

Comment: At each turn, there is only one correct turn to take you where you're trying to go, so a turn to the right would be "**a** right turn" while a turn in the correct direction would be "**the** right turn." As in "Take a right turn here" (right-left right) vs. "Is this the right turn?" (right-wrong right).

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish with context, or a follow-up question, unless the speaker is careful and says 'car on the right'. English speakers ask follow-up questions all the time. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "the car on the right" or "the correct car" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: But how would one know you didn't mean the more conservative car?

Comment: @HotLicks, just be glad it was a car not a [whale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_whale).